# Tables displaying incorrectly with jqm

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

I am attempting to add a jquery mobile table to a page and it should be straight forward but i cannot get it to display correctly. The code below works fine in a full browser and its the same way i have always made html tables.

```
    `<div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" name="hotOrderTable" id="hotOrderTable" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>!</td><td>Parts</td><td>Customer</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>foo1</td><td>foo2</td><td>foo3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foo4</td><td>foo5</td><td>foo6</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><!-- /table -->
    </div><!-- /main -->`
```

On my mobile browser the rows do not display on top of each other like they are supposed to. instead the table displays with all `<th>` elements in a single column and add `<td>` in the second column. if i add more rows it displays a column with the headers stacked again and the info to the right:

!      foo1
 
Parts  foo2
 
Customer foo3
!        foo4
Parts    foo5
Customer foo6

and so on

I have no idea what i am missing/overlooking

Comment: If you don't want to displax a table in JQM **reflow** mode, don't declare it... Use **columntoggle** instead and don't forget to add **data-priority** on the header cells.

Comment: @frequent yep that was it. knew i overlooked something simple, just needed another set of eyes. thank you